Pegar o tipo de input com PHP
E possivel pegar o tipo de Input com um codigo PHP?
Gostaria de saber se apos o submit o campo e um type="text", type="email" ou type="number", e assim poe dainte?

Esses tipos servem basicamente para o browser mostrar o campo de uma maneira diferente e mais "amigável" (por exemplo, date mostra um calendário, number não deixa digitar letras, etc). Mas ao enviar para o servidor (por exemplo, com POST ou GET), tudo é enviado como texto (os types "se perdem", pois só existem no HTML). No lado do PHP vc tem que saber o que é cada um, e converter as strings para o tipo apropriado.

Se o seu objetivo for validar usando informações fornecidas pela página renderizada no navegador, através desse atributo, qualquer pessoa poderia modificar isso sem o seu controle, quebrando sua aplicação ou até causando uma falha pior. O type serve para melhorar a experiência do usuário, em navegadores mobile geralmente é fornecido um teclado virtual adaptado para o tipo de campo, e mesmo em Desktops você terá alguma adaptação que facilitará para o usuário. Sua dúvida provavelmente é um problema XY.

Não, essa informação não é postada, até porque todos os valores de formulários são enviados como texto. Como foi comentado acima, a função desses tipos de campo é apenas adaptar a interface de edição conforme o tipo de informação e dispositivo.
Mas os names dos campos são postados, portanto você em teoria já sabe qual é o tipo, já que adicionou manualmente esses identificadores no HTML. O código PHP não tem como saber isso, a não ser que você adicione mais inputs com essas informações – o que geralmente é desnecessário e não faz muito sentido.

Era so um teste de um formulario dinamico qu to tentando montar, pelo que voce disse ou eu acho que entendi, eu consigo pegar o ID com php correto?

Você pega os valores dos input por ID no php

Não sei se está claro pra você, mas o PHP só monta o HTML (como string basicamente) e entrega pro browser. Qualquer coisa que você precise receber no php precisa ser postada (via submit de formulário ou ajax).

Não. Mas você consegue nomear cada campo por exemplo
<input type='text' name='data[text]'>
<input type='text' name='data[email]'>

Assim, você vai conseguir acessar no backend com $_POST['data']['text'] e $_POST['data']['email']
